# Unexpected certificate authority installation on an android

Tags: android, certificate-authority

Last week I received a notification pop-up on my galaxy s10 phone stating a certificate authority has been installed on this device. There was no information as to what authority was installed and none of the authorities listed in my phone display the installation date - only the issuing date, which cannot be used as an identifier.

My phone is using android version 12, so the only authorized users able to install the CA should be system admin and the settings application, as I understand it. F-secure internet security scan found no threats.

Now, how worried should I be? Is it reasonable to assume nothing has been compromised, or should I take countermeasures - like factory reseting my phone?

Edit: this is my personal phone, and it is not affiliated with any company vpn systems.

Comment: Did you install sth like an AdBlocker?

Comment: No, I have not.

Comment: Does it look like [this issue reported on Samsung Community](https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Other-Mobile-Devices/quot-Organization-installed-a-certificate-authority-in-your-work/td-p/2614110)?

Comment: Yes, it's the same issue!

Comment: Any user certificates installed?  I assume you're not using any VPN, such as a VPN service provided by your router? On pixel, you can see all the detail about every certificate installed on your phone (user or system) You should be able to do the same with Galaxy. Did you cick on the certificate to see its detail?  It should tell you its common name, who signed it and its expiration?  That what you need to know to determine whether you should be worried about this message or not.  If Galaxy doesn't give you this detail, can you export the installed certificates, so you can externally validate?

Comment: Is your system up-to-date?  If not, perform the system update.  An update could fix expired system certificates.  It not uncommon for certificates to expire in 2 to 3 years and if you haven't done an update, that certainly could be the problem. Whose your phone service provider? Did you check their site on issues with certificates?  They too could be responsible for keeping you System certificates up-to-date.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is an informational message indicating that you have a user certificate added to your phone. In my case, I got this warning because I've enabled my phone to be a vpn client. I don't remember whether I added the certificate to get it to work or whether it got added as part of the process of enabling a vpn client on my phone.

I recommend you look on your phone and see what user certificates you have installed.  You can look at

Settings > Security & Privacy > More security & privacy > Encryption & credentials > User credentials.

You will then get information that should help you identify the certificate you have installed. In my case the user credential I had installed said it was installed for VPN and apps and I could tell from the name that it was for my VPN server.  Please note that your phone also contains system-trusted certificates.  I believe that Android doesn't let you add System certificates only user certificates.  It does however allow you to disable any particular System certificate. There's no reason to do that unless you hear about a security breach where a particular trusted certificate authority had its private key stolen.  Then you can't trust any certificates signed by that certificate authority. If that happens, the breached certificate will get revoked by Google or your phone service provider.

For most users, you most likely don't need any user certificates installed. User certificates are used for establishing trust.  For example, when you visit a website using https, you get a certificate from that website.  That certificate is validated against the trusted certificates contained on your phone.  If the certificate was not signed by a trusted certificate, you'll get an error indicating that you don't trust the authenticity of that certificate. In other words, you might not be visiting the site you think you are visiting.  That's why you get the additional warning message that your secure traffic may be monitored or modified. If the user certificate is a certificate that you trust, then there's nothing to worry about.  I think is a new system check that just got added to your Android OS, and that's why you are now seeing that message.

Comment: You've oversimplified things too far to say that an arbitrary user doesn't need user certs. And your explanation of certs doesn't make sense in context. The use of user certs is on the rise and the trend will continue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't know the audience of this forum.  I'll stick with my claim that most smartphone users really don't have a need for adding a user certificates although there are exceptions such as for VPN services. As far as supporting information, I think I made it exactly clear where in the Android settings to look to see what  user certificates you have installed. That's important information to look at if you get an unexpected certificate authority. Sorry community, if my answer is not helpful, just delete it.

Comment: The other possibility for this error is that you've add a user certificate that doesn't not chain to a trusted root certificate. At which case you may need to add intermediary certificates and/or a root certificate (also know as a self-signed certificate).  I would think you would have gotten a error in adding a certificate that doesn't chain to a root certificate.

Comment: And lastly, certificate have an expiration date.  You could get this error if your phone has a certificate installed that has expired.  If you look at the certificates that you have installed on your, it should let you know if an installed certificate is not longer valid or if it's not signed by a trusted root certificate. Most likely it would be a User certificate.  Expired System certificates should be updated for you automatically by Google or your phone service provider.  I could find all this information about installed certificates on my Google Pixel, not sure about Samsung Galazy.